# How can I deal with the return of a null value parameter from a stored procedure to C# code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an application that gets a grade name and pass parameter from a stored procedure.  This works except for the case where there is no grade name in my grade table. Do I need to modify the parameters to make them accept null and/or do I need to modify the place where I assign those parameters to the C# parameters so I can make it accept a value or null?

I have this stored procedure. It's been shortened for this question:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_mark_test
    @GradeName    NVARCHAR(10) OUTPUT,
    @GradePass    BIT OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   -- Example only, real code does not hard code in 99
   SELECT top 1 @GradeName = Grade.Name, @GradePass = Grade.Pass
                FROM        AdminTest
                WHERE       TestId = 99 
END
```

Here is my C# code:

```
var sql = @"dbo.sp_mark_test @GradeName OUT,
                             @GradePass OUT";
SqlParameter[] parameters = new SqlParameter[] {             
   new SqlParameter("@GradeName", SqlDbType.NVarChar) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,Size = 10 },
   new SqlParameter("@GradePass", SqlDbType.Bit) { Direction = ParameterDirection.Output }            
};

await db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync(sql, parameters);
var GradeName = (string)parameters[1].Value;
var GradePass = (Boolean)parameters[2].Value;
```

Comment: check out `DBNull.Value`

Comment: @Drew - Thanks very much. If you think this is what I need could you add as an answer to the question so others could also see how to do this and so I can mark as answered.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As requested, and this is just a quick answer, look into the use of `DBNull` such as

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@closeDate", DBNull.Value);
```

or use it for comparisons.

MSDN Page on the [DBNull class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull(v=vs.110).aspx). A code snippet from it is below:

```
if (! DBNull.Value.Equals(row[fieldName])) 
    return (string) row[fieldName] + " ";    
else
    return String.Empty;
```

Comment: marc, if you find a suitable dupe close, I am all for it.