# Querying with EF6 using potentially empty Lists

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a function that takes 3 `string[]`, and then using EF6 queries my database to try to find a match. The lists can have nothing, one, or many variables in them.

```
using (var db= new Db(ConnectionString))
{
    var results =
                await
                    db.dbases.Where(
                                w =>
                                    portfolioSelected.Any(a => a == w.portfolio) &&
                                    statusSelected.Any(a => a == w.statusname) &&
                                    deskSelected.Any(a => a == w.assignedto)
                                ).ToListAsync();
}
```

When attempting this query, I get zero results back.

How can I write this so that the 3 lists can have any composition, including being empty, and I get the results I desire?

Comment: have you tried a == DBNull.Value ||  a == w.portfolio ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/34986244 if related

Comment: @easymoney202 I'm using the .Any() function of a string[], that won't work unfortunately, it's not a single value.

Comment: Break the where clause into three pieces. Only add the where clause if the argument list contains any items. Define your API behavior. Only then you will know if you have to use ORs or ANDs .

Comment: @JeroenHeier How do I do that? Break up my query that is?

Comment: var query = db.dbases; if (list1.count > 0) { query = query.Where(...); } ... var results = await query.ToListAsync();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Jeroen Heiers comment, I was able to break up the query by checking if the `string[]` was null, and creating my query in parts.

```
        using (var db = new Db(ConnectionString))
        {
            IQueryable<dbase> query = cmax.dbases.Where(w => w != null);
            var results = new List<dbase>();

                    if (portfolioSelected != null)
                        query = query.Where(w => portfolioSelected.Any(a => a == w.portfolio));
                    if (statusSelected != null)
                        query = query.Where(w => statusSelected.Any(a => a == w.statusname));
                    if (deskSelected != null)
                        query = query.Where(w => deskSelected.Any(a => a == w.assignedto)); break;


            results = await query.ToListAsync();
        }
```